# TAPI TE_CALLINFOCHANGE never fires

Tags: c#, tapi

I have been looking at TAPI, I can detect calls, make calls, answer/reject calls... however the only reason im even looking at it is to get the CallerID.

I know the hardware I am using works for CallerID as I have used other software to check before hand.

I have tired using the COM obeject directly, using JulMar's wrapper, and using TAPI 2.0 and I am yet to find a way that works.

From my understanding the callerID should come through via TE_CALLINFOCHANGE.

The problem is the event never fires, and the callerID is always blank on the other events.

Has anyone had success with this?

Thanks

Comment: I should point out that here in the UK, the caller ID is sent before the first ring...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be the TSP doesn't send the message about a call info change, and the information never changes because it is present from the start of the lifetime of the call.

The call info is always present for a call and you can ask for it at any time. Just retreive it from the call, with ITCallInfo::get_CallInfoLong (lineGetCallInfo).